# REST API to upload PDF's and index values to categories and Attributes in Open Text CS 10.5

Tags: opentext

I want to upload some documents to Open Text via the `REST API`'s. I have an Open Text `CS` set up, but I am not able to hit any of the `REST API`'s.

Also, I need to know how to map my document attributes to that with the categories/attributes in `Open Text` and upload the same to `CS`.

Comment: What is the version of your CS?

Comment: The Version of CS is 10.5

Answer (score 7):

Have you got the RestAPI Module installed?(sorry, had to ask)

You will find this on the Opentext Support Site and will need a valid login to download it.

Have you looked at these freely available guides on the Opentext Developer Site?, including;

- [OpenText RESTful API standard](https://developer.opentext.com/awd/resources/articles/868/opentext+restful+api+standard)
- [REST API - Quick Start Guide](https://developer.opentext.com/awd/resources/articles/6102/content+server+rest+api++quick+start+guide)

These should help you get started.

There is also an excellent guide to using Postman (Chrome Plugin) to test connections and get to know the api.

- [Using Postman for Content Server RestAPI](https://developer.opentext.com/awd/forums/questions/4979527/postman+rest+client+chrome+extension+used+for+content+server+api)

You will likely need to consult the [Content Server API v1 (2014-06)](https://developer.opentext.com/awd/resources/apis/content-server-v1.1) to figure out what you need to put in to access all the features.

Comment: Thank you for posting this info! Really helped me out a ton! :)